# System Center 2012 VMM UI is very slow

Tags: system-center, scvmm

I've recently setup system center 2012 a new server 2008 r2 server which I'm using for virtual machines.  Everything seems to be working fine, and the virtual machines are nice and fast.

But the Virtual Machine Manager interface is always excruciatingly slow.  Sometimes taking up to 15 seconds moving between screens.  It's very frustrating trying to use it when a task that just involves a couple clicks ends up taking several minutes.  Pages that have a lot of form fields seem to take the longest to load - such as the page to change hardware settings of a virtual machine.

When opening a VM's properties page, I can actually watch it draw and redraw each element on the screen over and over again.

Is this just normal performance for VMM?  If not, where can I look to find what is slowing it down.

Nothing else on the system seems to suffer.  I can load and use Hyper-V manager with no noticable slowness.  Even programs like event viewer that are usually rather slow seem to load fairly fast.  Only the system center programs seem slow.

Server is a Dell R710, 2x16 core opteron 6274 processors, 96GB RAM.
OS drive is 2x500GB 7.2k RPM SAS drives in RAID1 (opted for the less expensive 7.2k drives since pretty much everything is stored on the SAN).

I'm accessing the server through remote desktop on a 1GB LAN.

Am I just being impatient?  Does anyone else use VMM 2012 and find it slow?

Edit:  Having installed the client software on my local machine, it runs much better.  Does SCVMM need a good video card to run well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use it, and yes, it is a little slow.  It's definitely slower than VMM 2008 R2 was.  15 seconds between moving screens is definitely longer than what we see here, so maybe you've got something else going on.  I'm hoping it gets sped up when SP1 releases.

Answer (score 1):

We are running SP1 beta and it is very slow.  It is responsive most of the time, but definitely not as snappy as it needs to be.  Hopefully it is because we're running SP1 beta...